# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list - What do i do?

Tags: python, html, flask, typeerror

I keep getting the error "
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list" and im not sure on how to fix it what do i need to change?

```
@app.route("/browse/<where>")
def collectPage(where):
    for item in lostItems:
        if item[1] == where:
            passedItem = lostItems[item]
    return render_template("mainPage.html", collect = Collect, item = passedItem)
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of `lostItems` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def collectPage(where):
    for item in range(len(lostItems)):
        if item[1] == where:
            passedItem = lostItems[item]
    return render_template("mainPage.html", collect = Collect, item = passedItem)
```

Or

```
def collectPage(where):
    for item in lostItems:
        if item[1] == where:
            passedItem = item
    return render_template("mainPage.html", collect = Collect, item = passedItem)
```

Comment: How can you use `item[1]` if `item` is of type `int`?

Comment: to support that, we have to check type using if condition

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `lostItems` is a nested list. and when you use `lostItems[item]` you are getting the error. you can change your statement to `passedItem = item`.

```
@app.route("/browse/<where>")
def collectPage(where):
    for item in lostItems:
        if item[1] == where:
            passedItem = item
    return render_template("mainPage.html", collect = Collect, item = passedItem)
```

or you can use `enumetrate` to access the list index.

```
@app.route("/browse/<where>")
def collectPage(where):
    for indx,item in enumerate(lostItems):
        if item[1] == where:
            passedItem = lostItems[indx]
    return render_template("mainPage.html", collect = Collect, item = passedItem)
```